# Two externally touching circles inscribed in a third circle

Tags: circles

Suppose two circles($C_1,C_2$) touch each other externally. How many different circles($C$) can be drawn such that these two circles touch it internally?

I made a quick rough sketch of how it looks:

[image]

The thick black inner circles are $C_1,C_2$ and the thinner black, red and green circles are possible $C$s

It seems like I can draw an infinite number of circles $C$ satisfying the condition. Am I right in saying so?

If yes, is there a relationship between the radii of $C$s?

Also, are there any texts or sources that talk about this?

Comment: I’m guessing that the locus of centers is one branch of a hyperbola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $O$ is the center of a circle of radius $R$ tangent to the circles $C(O_1, R_1)$, $C(O_2, R_2)$ then we have
$$OO_i = R- R_i$$
$i=1,2$, and so
$$OO_1 - OO_2= R_2 - R_1$$

Conversely, if $OO_1 - OO_2= R_2 - R_1$, then take $R = OO_i + R_i$, $i=1,2$. Note that such points $0$ exist ( infinitely many) as long as $|R_2 - R_1| < O_1 O_2$, that is, as long as the two initial circles are not one containing the other.

Comment: +1. Such $O$ lie on one branch of a hyperbola (unless $R_1=R_2$).

Comment: And if the two radii are equal the radius is a straight line

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that

- circle $C_1$ has radius $r_1$ and is centered at the point $P_1$
- circle $C_2$ has radius $r_2$ and is centered at the point $P_2$.

Let the center of the outer tangent circle be at the point $P=(x,y)$.

Then, as the other answer demonstrates
$$
dist(P,P_1) - dist(P,P_2) = r_1 - r_2
$$
This immediately shows that the guess I made in my comment is correct: in fact $P$ lies on (one branch of) a hyperbola with foci at $P_1$ and $P_2$.

If you want to know the equation of the hyperbola and it’s asymptotes, that’s all worked out very nicely in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621086/is-there-geometric-proof-for-the-equation-of-hyperbola-using-only-constant-dista).

The algebra will work out more cleanly if you work in a coordinate system where $P_1 = (-a,0)$ and $P_2= (a,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! :)